# Between SVG and canvas, which is better suited for manipulating/animating several images? Maybe neither and just use css3 transforms?

Tags: javascript, canvas, css, svg

The 2nd part of the question is, which javascript library is better/easier to manipulate images with? I won't be actually drawing any shapes or anything. Other info: I'll be using jQuery and don't need to support all browsers, just webkit.

**Edit:**
More information: the current design is to layout/draw several rows/columns of images in a grid-like layout, with the image in the center being in "focus" (a little larger, with a border or something and some text next to it). The tricky thing is that we want the whole canvas of images to appear to slide/glide over to bring another random image into focus. So obviously the number of images in this grid needs to exceed what is visible in the viewport so that when the transition occurs there are always images occupying the canvas. Other than moving the images around, I won't be blurring them or otherwise modifying them. Eventually we will add user interactions like clicking/touching on a visible image to bring it to focus manually.

Let me know if this is not clear or still confusing.

I ran across [scripty2](http://scripty2.com) which seems like an alternative to using canvas/SVG for my purposes. I also started farting around with [EaselJS](http://easeljs.com) last night, and it seems like this might work, but I'm wondering if it'll end up being more work/complex than just using standard HTML/CSS and a tool like Scripty2 to aid with animations and click/touch events. Just looking for any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a rough description or a link to something similar to what you intend to do? The answer depends on many factors, but in you're case I'm guessing it's between canvas and css3 transforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on your manipulation and animation.

If it's just translations, [CSS wins for speed](http://phrogz.net/tmp/image_move_speed.html) compared to canvas. I haven't tested, but I feel confident it easily beats SVG for the same sort of thing.

If you're going to be doing non-affine transformations or otherwise messing with the images (e.g. blurring them) you clearly want Canvas.

If you need event handlers per object, you clearly want a retained-mode drawing system like SVG or HTML+CSS. I haven't done enough CSS3 transforms to say how they compare in terms of speed to SVG, but they clearly do not have the robust [transformation DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html) of SVG.

This is a rather subjective question (or suite of questions) and you haven't yet given sufficient information for a clear answer to be possible.

Comment: @Phorgz I am also in a similar situation. Check out my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511707/storing-design-information/21512111?noredirect=1#21512111